# Football League coincidence

Tags: conditional-probability

In the English Championship division, there are 24 teams, 8 of which have names starting with the letter B (e.g.Bolton) Tonight, (5th March 2013) all 24 teams in this division are playing each other. By a coincidence, the 8 teams starting with B are playing each other, i.e. 4 of the games involve these 8 teams (there are 2 teams per game!) What is the probability of this happening ?

Comment: **100%.** That is a serious answer (and one of the infinitely many correct ones) intended to reveal the need for a clearer context for the question: (objective) probability statements are nonsensical without a description of what experiment is being performed and what constitutes an independent replication of it.  Would you care to clarify these things?

Comment: I am simply asking what the probability is of this occurring - given that the choice of teams was entirely random and that the outcome was as I described. I do not understand your point about independent replication.

Comment: Let's assume that the choice of teams was random. (It was not, by the way, but save that for later.) There still is no "probability" until we clarify what the event is. Could it be a random pairing for tonight only? Could it be the chance that such a pairing occurs somewhere in this year's schedule? The chance that such a pairing might ever occur in the division? Or--more subtly--should the event in question be described as "somebody succeeds in characterizing tonight's pairing in some idiosyncratic but irrelevant way that makes it appear unusual"? I think the last might be closest to reality.

Comment: For the sake of this exercise,can we just assume it is a random pairing for that night only. Somebody did idiosyncratically succeeded in characterized the pairing as unusual.

Comment: With that final clarification--thank you!--I am satisfied that there is a definite question here (+1).

Answer (score 1):

The total number of ways for teams to be assigned to play each other is $23 * 21 * \dots * 1$. There are 23 ways for the first team to choose an opposing team and then those two are removed. There are 21 ways for the next team to choose an opposing team, etc.

There are $7*5*3*1$ ways for the B teams to get matched up.  The first B team has 7 options to choose from, the next has 5, etc.

There are $(23-8) * (21-8) * \dots * (9-8)$ ways for non B teams to get matched up.

Putting this together gives:

$$
\frac{(7*5*3*1) * ((23-8) * (21-8) * \dots * (9-8))}{
23 * 21 * \dots * 1}
=
\frac{(105)(2027025)}{316234143225}
=
0.0006730381
$$

So there's about a $0.067\%$ chance of this happening randomly if each team is equally likely to play each other team.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification. I really appreciate your help with this one.